# How to apply WHERE clause to relationship class using ArcObjects?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, arcobjects, c#

I'm trying to query objects related to objects and satisfying some query in ArcObjects. `IRelationshipClass` interface contains methods for getting all related objects but how can one filter them? I don't believe that such ability doesn't exist.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at the **IRelationshipClass2** interface, this has a method *GetObjectsMatchingObjectSetEx* which allows you to place a queryfilter.

Comment: Unfortunately IRelationshipClass2 .GetObjectsMatchingObjectSetEx throws Not implemented exception in ArcGIS 10.1.

Comment: That new information would be useful for you to edit into your question, or to raise as a new question.